# Make to not show numbers after decimal

Tags: java, android-studio

Input :

```
double a = 21.66468                     
double b = 21.86494

String output_a = Sting.format("%.0f",a);
String output_b = Sting.format("%.0f",b);
```

Output :

```
output_a = 22              
output_b = 22
```

**But i want output** :

```
output_a = 21                 
output_b = 21
```

*Here the problem is it's increasing the number by 1 automatically*

Comment: 21.66468 and 21.86494 to the nearest whole number is 22... try using the built in Math.floor to round down `String output_b = String.format("%.0f", Math.floor(b));`

Answer (score 2):

Simply cast to int

System.out.println("double a: " + (int)a);
System.out.println("double b: " + (int)b);

Answer (score 1):

The underlying [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) says that *"the value will be rounded using the round half up algorithm"* and it apparently does not offer direct options to prevent that.

What you seem to want is not rounding but truncating and a simple way of doing that is casting to `int`:

```
jshell> double a = 21.66468;
a ==> 21.66468

jshell> System.out.println((int) a);
21
```

Or to get the `String`:

```
jshell> double a = 21.66468;
a ==> 21.66468

jshell> String output_a = Integer.toString((int) a);
output_a ==> "21"
```

Answer (score 1):

In such a case you will want to utilize the Math.floor() java method...

something like this

```
double a = 21.66468                     
double b = 21.86494

// This trancates you doubles and later casts them into integers
int aWithNoDecimals = (int) Math.floor(a);
int bWithNoDecimals = (int) Math.floor(a);


/* 
   You do not want to use Strings here... 
   You can just output the ints and you are good
*/

//String output_a = Sting.format("%.0f",a);
//String output_b= Sting.format("%.0f",b);

// Something like this
int output_a = aWithNoDecimals;
int output_b = bWithNoDecimals;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i will demonstrate you that how to make your decimal number short. Here i am going to make it short upto 4 value after decimal.

double value = 12.3457652133
  value =Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat(